# Align menu button to the top right

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is easy and my code is a mess, I am super new to CSS and formatting. I am just trying to move the button over to the top right corner of the screen. I have tried using float and text-align, those don't appear to work.

Here is my HTML

```css
.container{
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container h1{
  padding:0;
  margin:2px;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

#main-header{
  background-color: white;
  color: #2c3659;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-button{
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}

.button-photo{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbutton{
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #2c3659;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header id = "main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Website Name</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-button">
      <button type="button" class="navbutton"> Menu </button>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `flex` in `#main-header`, so that you need to add `justify-content:space-between` in it to move menu right side

```css
.container{
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container h1{
  padding:0;
  margin:2px;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

#main-header{
  background-color: white;
  color: #2c3659;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-button{
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}

.button-photo{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbutton{
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #2c3659;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header id = "main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Website Name</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-button">
      <button type="button" class="navbutton"> Menu </button>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: flex` in the `main-header` class and `justify-content: space-between` in the `navbar-button` class.
And you don't need to write the width in the `main-header h1`. It will make your title looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.navbutton {
  float:right;
}
```